# Setting headless as CLI arg

Tags: protractor

My Protractor suite generally uses the Chrome non-headless mode so the tests can be monitored and stuff, but I tend to switch often between headless and normal while writing tests. Constantly changing the conf.js file is a hassle so I'd like to be able to do this via a command line argument. Something like the following:

`npm test -- --headless`

`npm test-headless`

As you can see I'm running Protractor via npm, so a complex argument construction is not a problem here.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this using uncle Google. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

keep it simle. Create two `protractor.conf` files: 
- one for local (`non headless` purpose) - `protractor.local.conf`
- another for `headless` purpose that you have already had
And create some scripts that will run what you need, for example:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test-headless": "node ./config/protractor.headless.conf.js",
    "test-local": "node ./config/protractor.local.conf.js",
  }
```

Comment: I could, but I feel like it would add unnecessary file clutter. It's a good workaround, but not the elegant solution I'm looking for.

Comment: as I wrote at the start, keep it simple ;)

Comment: I don't think duplicating all configuration into two files is kind of "keeping it simple". The simplier solution would be adding a command flag overriding the behaviour of protractor.conf.js.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat hackish solution, but it works! Check for this flag (or any other) in your configuration file using node's [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) global. You can then dynamically configure Protractor accordingly. This is one of the great perks of JS config files.

*For example:*

```js
const isHeadless = process.argv.includes('--headless');

exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        isHeadless && '--headless'
      ].filter(Boolean)
    }
  }
};
```

This *does* raise a warning in the Protractor CLI:

> Ignoring unknown extra flags: headless. This will be an error in
>   future versions, please use --disableChecks flag to disable the 
>   Protractor CLI flag checks.

As with all hacks you use them with some level of risk. The `--disableChecks` flag will get rid of the warning and future error, but may introduce other issues.